# URL Rewrites And Layered Navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, url-rewrite

Is it normal for urls to not be rewritten when using Layered Navigation to click thru categories?

For example: A category when clicking via the main top menu is:

http://www.mywebsite.com/clothing/accessories

But when clicking the same category via the Layered Navigation comes up as:

http://www.mywebsite.com/clothing?cat=10

I also notice that the Category Name does not change when using Layered Navigation. I have not noticed this until now so am not sure if this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. The first example is that of a category, whose URL is rewritten.

That second one is that of the category "Clothing" with a filtering parameter. In your case, you went to this category and selected, using the layered navigation, category with ID 10, which I'm assuming is Accessories.

Layered navigation-filtered pages don't get URL rewrites. I'm not too familiar with rewrites, but I don't believe I've seen a Magento site that does it.